# How to reference child controllers of a certain type from an angular directive or component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I define an angular component or directive, I can use 'require' to bind to a parent controller like `require: {'parentForm' : '^^ngForm'}`.

I'd like to do the same thing, but in reverse:  `require: {'childrenForms' : '[children]ngForm'}` would bind childrenForms to an array of all controllers contained within my component which are ngForms.

I want to do this in order to build components that add aggregate behavior to directives I don't have control over.  For example my-special-form container could have an isValid() method that returns true if all the ng-forms within it are valid at the moment.

Is there any way to do this?  Am I making a mistake by even wanting to?

Comment: Last time I checked, you can't. What you can do is have the child directives register with the parent. In the past, I've created directives inside 3rd party ones that require both the 3rd party controller and a parent *registry* controller for handling such cases.

Comment: You can't do this is because directives are compiled from parents to children. This defines the direction in which the communication should be performed - from children to parents. This suggests the way how it should be done - `children` directives should `require` parent controller and call its method, e.g. `registerChild` to make it aware of them. Due to the fact that parent contents may vary and children may appear and disappear, it is usually more appropriate to make them loosely coupled and broadcast scope events to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to `require` inner child directive in Angular. Personally I don't think so the approach you thought about would be good approach to go for, like here parent directive want to know directly about child directive. Rather I'd say choose the approach where child directive will pass required data to parent controller by calling one of its method.

If you only wanted to validate inner forms then you can wrap all the inner forms inside wrapper form `ng-form` with some name(you can have nested form in angular using `ng-form` directive). You can see example below, where you can see I wrapped all the inner form with one wrapper form element `ng-form`. So what happen is, when any one of the forms get invalid the parent form will invalid. If all forms are valid then `parentForm` will become `valid` as well.

**Markup**

```
{{parentForm.$valid}}
<div ng-form name="parentForm" my-directive>
   <form name="form1" some-directive>
     .....
   </form>
   <form name="form2" some-directive>
     .....
   </form>
   <form name="form3" some-directive>
     .....
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The ng-form isValid thing was just an example, but I appreciate the information.  I ended up combining what you and Phil said in my solution.  (I "tag" the third party directive with my own directive which registers it with the parent.)